# Rails API only - decode Google JWT without user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, jwt, google-authentication

My application is separated into a Rails 5 API-only app and a React frontend.

I would like to be able to log in to the frontend React application with Google and receive a JWT.

For each request to the API, I will send the JWT to the Rails application as an Authorization header.

I would like to be able to decode this Authorization token on each action so that I will not need user models or sessions on the API. When I decode the JWT, I will verify that the email matches a certain URL and if it does not, I will deny access to the method.

My question is: How do I correctly and securely decode the JWT from Google? The Google application has a client secret key, etc. but I am not sure where this goes in the [JWT gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) decode method.

When I decode an Authorization token using the following parameters, the information is correct. I do not think this is the best way because JWTs can be faked and using this method, the token is never actually verified by Google. Here is my authentication method:

```
def authenticate_user
  token = request.authorization
  head 403 and return unless token
  decoded_token = JWT.decode token, nil, false
  hd = decoded_token[0]["hd"]
  head 403 and return unless hd == "example.com"
end
```

This is ran in a `before_action` call in the ApplicationController:

```
before_action :authenticate_user
```

Like I said before, this actually works. The problem is that it never verifies the Google identity and that any token passed to it could be faked for this reason.

How can I securely decode the token passed to me without creating a user model? I just want to verify that, with every request, the token that is sent is correct, secure, and the `hd` is from the correct domain.

I do have a client secret from my Google app, but I'm not sure where this even comes in to play.

Comment: method signature `def decode(jwt, key = nil, verify = true, custom_options = {}, &keyfinder)` seems like the second argument would be your secret key [GitHub Source](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt.rb#L119) I would make sure this is an environment variable because otherwise, if you are using public source control, your secret wont be secret for very long.

Comment: Thanks for your response @engineersmnky.

The problem is why do I need that if I can just decode it without it? What does adding that in even do and why is it necessary if the JWT can be decoded without using it? 

Also how can I verify it is not a fake token and that it is, in fact, from Google?

Comment: I would assume the default verify = true would provide that verification step. Yours probably works currently since you are setting verify to false so it just assumes the JWT is valid